# How to run a very small program more optimally in Java

Tags: java, windows, algorithm, jvm, java-7

I am running a very small program where I simulate playing the lottery. I am noticing that in my Windows task manager, it is taking over 100MBs of RAM even though I know I am only using a few memory blocks.

I believe the JVM is defaulting me to using some 128MB default value of RAM. It got me thinking -- is there a way to force the JVM to bypass the RAM and run in the cache, or heap, or some faster area of memory?

If we don't have that level of control, what JVM arguments would allow for very a program that requires more speed than memory?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch;

static final PrintStream err = System.err;
static final PrintStream out = System.out;

private static void studyOdds() {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 75; i++)
        list1.add(new Integer(i));

    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
        list2.add(new Integer(i));

    ArrayList<Integer> winner = null;

    Deque<Long> winIndx = new LinkedList<>();
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch(), sw2 = new StopWatch(), sw3 = new StopWatch();
    sw.start();
    sw2.start();
    sw3.start();
    for (long i = 0; i <= 1000000000L; i++) {
        Collections.shuffle(list1);
        Collections.shuffle(list2);
        ArrayList<Integer> pick = new ArrayList<>(6);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            pick.add(list1.get(j));
        Collections.sort(pick);
        pick.add(list2.get(0));

        if (winner == null) {
            winner = (ArrayList<Integer>) pick.clone();
            out.println("Winning #s are: " + winner);
            winIndx.addLast(0L);
        } else if (winner.equals(pick)) {
            err.format(
                    "Found it!%n%s%nWinner count = %d/%s%nPicks since last = %s%nTotal time to find = %s%n",
                    pick, winIndx.size(), fi(i),
                    fi(i - winIndx.peekLast()), sw2);
            winIndx.addLast(i);
            sw2.reset();
            sw2.start();
        }
        if (i % 100000000L == 0 && i > 0) {
            out.format("i = %s%ntime = %s%ntime since last = %s%n", fi(i),
                    sw, sw3);
            sw3.reset();
            sw3.start();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total time: " + sw);
}

static final String fi(final long i) {
    return NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(i);
}
```

Comment: A loop of what 100 million is that containing a `new`? That's going to allocate a lot of memory. GC will eventually be invoked, but until it is...

Comment: How big does `winIndx` get?

Comment: "force the JVM to bypass the RAM" that doesn't make sense. Your system doesn't have anything faster than RAM except for a few megabytes of cache which it has to share with all other applications and the operating system and has very little control over. I have trouble seeing what your actual goal is.

Comment: Actually yes -- the "new" call in each loop was causing the extra memory usage. Well this changes things! I have always been taught that in Java, you don't need to worry about re-creating dynamic memory in loops. Instead, the GC will handle it. But, since the GC is always a bit delayed, you can expect a memory-leak type behavior on a limited scale if you don't reuse memory.

Comment: Err, the heap and the stack are *in* the RAM. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of that memory is virtual. Java tends to overprovision and grab more memory than it needs sometimes but that memory is not actually physically mapped until used. You should be able to check physical vs virtual memory usage to see the difference.

If what you're seeing is physical usage then just try to allocate less within your application or let things that are no longer needed drop out of scope quickly.